# Coinbase API returning "message" but no actual message

Tags: python, coinbase-api, cryptocurrency

Using danpaquin's cbpro package, I am then calling 'auth_client.get_fills' method to request all the order fills for a particular product Coinbase offers. For example:

```
all_fills = {}
for product in products:
    all_fills[product] = []
    fills = a.get_fills(product)
    for fill in fills:
        for x,y in fill.items():
            print(f"\t{x}: {y}")
        print(fill)
        all_fills[product].append(fill)
    print(f"{product} captured.")
```

For reference, "products" in my program is a list of all the coin-pairings that Coinbase offers. "ETH-USD", "LTC-USD", etc.

.get_fills() returns a generator of all the order fills for that particular product.

My problem here is that on some products, the iteration (fill) returned by the generator (fills) is literally the string, "message". Naturally, this produces an error, per my code above.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

It's my understanding from the Coinbase documentation that errors are returned in the form of a json, whereby "message" is one of the keys.

If this is in fact just the key to an error message of sorts, or a completion message, or whatever it may be... I would like to be able to see the actual contents of the message, instead of just the string "message". Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

> It's my understanding from the Coinbase documentation that errors are returned in the form of a json, whereby "message" is one of the keys.

Correct! According to the official Coinbase documentations (see https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#errors) a call resulting with an error will output the following:

```
{
"message": "Invalid Price"
}
```

, hence a JSON or dictionary format - whatever way you want to decode it.
In this case you could retrieve the value of the error message via `dictionary_name['message']`.

Another possibility would be to use the json standard library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and dump the whole dictionary itself via `json.dumps(dictionary_name)`.